# Insert in Merge not working in Oracle

Tags: oracle, merge, upsert

I am new to Oracle. 
I have a table in Oracle which has 4 columns Period, Open_Flag,Creation_Dt,Updated_By.
The Period column is the Primary key of the table. 
 [image]
I have created a proc which will check the value of period from input parameter in the table, if its existing, the value of Open_flag has to be updated else a new record shall be inserted. 
`create or replace 
PROCEDURE                                                                                                                                   PROC_REF_SAP_PERIOD(
V_PERIOD IN NUMBER,V_OPEN_FLAG IN VARCHAR2,V_CREATION_DT IN  DATE,V_UPDATED_BY IN VARCHAR2) 
 AS 
BEGIN 
MERGE INTO REF_SAP_PERIOD T 
USING (SELECT * FROM REF_SAP_PERIOD WHERE PERIOD=V_PERIOD  )S 
ON (T.PERIOD=S.PERIOD  ) 
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET OPEN_FLAG = V_OPEN_FLAG --WHERE PERIOD=V_PERIOD AND   CREATION_DT=V_CREATION_DT AND   UPDATED_BY=V_UPDATED_BY
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (PERIOD,OPEN_FLAG,CREATION_DT,UPDATED_BY) VALUES (V_PERIOD,V_OPEN_FLAG,V_CREATION_DT,V_UPDATED_BY);
END;`

 The issue is that the Update is working well in this case, however, the insert is not working.
 Please help.

Comment: Please, text [not  screenshots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Say I want to help you; if you had posted some text, I could easily copy the code, try and edit it; if you post an image, I simply vote to close the question.

Comment: Sorry @Aleksej ...I have now updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

You are merging table with itself, filtered by period. Obviously, it will never see your non-existent values in itself.

Try this line instead of your USING line:

```
using (select V_PERIOD "period" from dual)S
```

Comment: Thanks @Alexander , you just saved my day .Much appreciated.